# Как передать в QDataStream - QList<пользовательская структура>?

Tags: qt, c++11

Есть функция по загрузке данных с файла с помощью QDataStream:

```
void tgTableModel::Load(QString &path)
{
QFile file(path);
if(file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly))
{
    m_ptargetList->clear();

    QList<target> list; //target моя структура
    QDataStream in(&file);
    in.setVersion(QDataStream::Qt_5_7);
    in >> list;
    m_ptargetList = &list;
    file.close();
}
}
```

Для того,что бы это сработало, я определил функции для структуры target:

```
struct target{
  QString name;
  QString description;
  int priority;
  QDate deadline;
  Status::Value ready;
};

QDataStream &operator << (QDataStream &stream, const target &tg)
{
  stream << tg.name;
  stream << tg.description;
  stream << tg.priority;
  stream << tg.deadline;
  stream << tg.ready;
  return stream;
}

QDataStream &operator >> (QDataStream &stream, target  &tg)
{
  stream >> tg.name;
  stream >> tg.description;
  stream >> tg.priority;
  stream >> tg.deadline;
  stream >> tg.ready;
  return stream;
}
```

А так же определил функции для работы stream >> tg.ready; и stream << tg.ready;

```
class Status: public QObject
{
Q_OBJECT

public:
explicit Status(QObject * parent = nullptr): QObject(parent){}
enum /*class*/ Value{in_waiting, deferred, completed, in_process, nVariant};
Q_ENUM(Value)

friend QDataStream &operator << (QDataStream &stream, const Status::Value &val)
{
    stream << (int)val;
    return stream;
}
friend QDataStream &operator >> (QDataStream &stream, Status::Value &val)
{
    stream >> (int)val; // вот тут выбивает 4 ошибки!!!
    return stream;
}
};
```

Но в указанном месте выбивает 4 одинаковых ошибки, что бы я не делал:
"...ошибка: C2679: binary '>>': no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'int' (or there is no acceptable conversion)"

Помогите исправить, плс. Заранее спасибо!

Comment: А если так `int i; stream >> i; val = i;`?

Comment: `friend QDataStream &operator >> (QDataStream &stream, Status::Value &val)
    {
        quint32 num;
        stream >> num;
        val = static_cast<Status::Value>(num);
        return stream;
    }`
В итоге 17 ошибок: "mainwindow.obj:-1: ошибка: LNK2005: "class QDataStream & __cdecl operator>>(class QDataStream &,struct target &)" (??5@YAAEAVQDataStream@@AEAV0@AEAUtarget@@@Z) already defined in main.obj"

Comment: Ну это уже лучше, раньше были ошибки компиляции, а теперь ошибки линковки:)

Comment: И что дальше делать?

Comment: В самом конце еще такая ошибка есть "debug\Organizer.exe:-1: ошибка: LNK1169: one or more multiply defined symbols found"

Comment: Можно пример на котором воспроизводится ошибка?

Comment: Все спасибо. Просто надо было сделать эти функции inline или разделить декларацию и реализацию по h и cpp файлам.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
inline QDataStream &operator << (QDataStream &stream, const target &tg)
{
  stream << tg.name;
  stream << tg.description;
  stream << tg.priority;
  stream << tg.deadline;
  quint32 Num = static_cast<quint32>(tg.ready);
  stream << Num;
  return stream;
}

inline QDataStream &operator >> (QDataStream &stream, target  &tg)
{
  stream >> tg.name;
  stream >> tg.description;
  stream >> tg.priority;
  stream >> tg.deadline;
  quint32 Num;
  stream >> Num;
  tg.ready = static_cast<Status::Value>(Num);
  return stream;
}
```

Вот так компилируется.